# WPF MVVM Window navigation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, window

I'm applying the MVVM pattern to my application that will have dozens of screens (with the respectives ViewModels). Now I'm stuck in a very simple point ... who has the responsibility to create the new window, instantiate the viewModel and assign one to another?

I think is wrong to do this in the View or even in the ViewModel. I saw many replies advising the use of external frameworks, that is not an option to me.

What do you think?

What is the official Windows recommendation?

Comment: There are many question about MVVM and navigation just look at the right hand column...

Comment: Thats true, the thing is every answer is about using some third party framework or make use of a single window with a global ViewModel.
My problem is how to switch between different Windows without using third party frameworks or doing it directly in the viewModel code.

Comment: What about Unity? Is that an option? (third party, but Microsoft and for free)

Comment: I would guess the official Windows recommendation would be to use [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) but this is an external framework (although it is free and developed by Microsoft)

Comment: What is the exact problem about third party software? Is Microsoft considered a third party? that would make decissions really hard (mscore is also third party then?)

Answer (score 0):

this is what i do:

- 1 mainwindow with mainviewmodel as application root
- Loginview with viewmodel when needed
- viewmodel first approach for all childs/modules
- dialogservice viewmodel driven for dialogs
- windowservice viewmodel driven for windows

the mainviewmodel compose the modules via MEF.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try an example: the user clicks a button and a confirmation dialog box is shown with Yes/No.
Normally you would raise the notification in the event handler of the button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, MouseRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Confirm?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (result == true)
        //something
    else
        //something else
}
```

Now, since we have MVVM, the *business logic* (here the `if/else`) must be moved into the ViewModel. But the *UI* must remain on the UI control!
Suppose this is the ViewModel:

```
public class VM
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //raise the confirmation interaction
    }
}
```

The ViewModel can't own the UI... but can own an ABSTRACTION of the interaction required with the user.

This may be the interface of the interaction:

```
public interface IConfirmationInteraction
{
    bool? RaiseConfirmationRequest(string message);
}
```

So the ViewModel can have a property like this:

```
public IConfirmationInteraction ConfirmInteraction { get; }
```

`VM` does not instantiate it, `VM` accepts an instance of the interface passed by someone else. For example in the constructor:

```
public VM(IConfirmationInteraction confirmInteraction)
{
    if (confirmInteraction == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(confirmInteration));
    ConfirmInteraction = confirmInteraction;
}
```

So its method can become:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var result = ConfirmInteraction.RaiseConfirmationRequest("Confirm?");
    if (result == true)
        //do something
    else
        //do something else
}
```

And the UI? You can create a concrete interaction that uses UI elements:

```
public class UIConfirmationInteraction : IConfirmationInteraction
{
    public bool? RaiseConfirmationRequest(string message)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(message, MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    }
}
```

Do you see the point? We have saved the pattern: the ViewModel acts with the logic, putting together different abstractions, but knows nothing about the implementations, about message boxes, buttons, etc..
You can implement those interactions as UI interactions, for example in the constructor of the UI Control that owns the `VM`:

```
public class MyControl : USerControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        DataContext = new VM(new UIConfirmationInteraction());
    }
}
```

But you can also implement them as automatic results, for example when you want to run a test list trying a default answer of "yes" or a default answer of "no":

```
public class YesConfirmationInteraction : IConfirmationInteraction
{
    public bool? RaiseConfirmationRequest(string message)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is called "**dependency injection**". try it on Google, you can find dozens of tutorials. In this case, I've build a dependency injection *by constructor*.

This is a solid way in which you can build manually all the bridges between the UI controls, through the ViewModels, but preserving the pattern.