# Moq with c# System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq

I'm currently writing some unit tests around a WPF module of a program. I've come to a point where a `ShowMessage` returns a `Yes` or `No` value within the statement.

```
dService.ShowMessage(view, args);
```

The args takes a lambda as (shortened)

```
new MessageArgs(arg1, arg2, arg3, (la) => 
{
   if (la.result == messResult.yes)
   {
   // do something
   }
}
```

I'm now trying to mock the result given back from this lambda but am having some difficulty and have been unable to find someone with a similar problem.

I've tried setting a default result within the lambda in my unit test:

```
new MessageArgs(arg1, arg2, arg3, (la) => 
{
   if (la.result == messResult.yes)
   {
       la.result = messResult.yes;
   }
}
```

Which proved unsuccessful along with trying to set the arg result below the statement as:

```
args.result = messResult.yes;
```

I have also tried to use Setup as:

```
dServiceMock.Setup(x => x.ShowMessage)
```

but there is no return property as `ShowMessage` is a void function.

None have shown a change in action from my unit test. Has anyone else had a similar "problem" and found a solution or know of some documentation around this? I'll update this if I find something in the mean time.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you wrap this method in another one that returns a boolean and unit test that new method ? Any other way would be called UI testing (testing the actual message that is shown in the message box).

Comment: Can you show code that you want to unit test?

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39214839/4165377) can give you some idea around the problem of abstracting UI interactions

Comment: @user3185569 I cannot edit the source code of the project at this point, which causes issues as it apparently wasn't wrote to be tested.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I cannot show the full code as it's my companies code base and I'm not sure what they'll be like but if you need some specifics I can create some "mock" recreations.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Thanks for that, I'll read through it, but it doesn't seem to be specific to Moq, but it does look like it will be useful for creating future applications. Thank you.

Comment: You should post [MCVE] - no one needs your original source code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The code I want to unit test in shown in the first and second code examples. It is a showMessage which returns a Yes or No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dService` is not an instance of a `sealed` class, create a subclass which overrides that `ShowMessage` method in a way you need for your test purposes.

Edit:

The problem arises by the `dService.ShowMessage(view, args)` call encapsulating two (or more) actions:
- calls view.ShowMessage
- calls the lambda enclosed in args with the result of view.ShowMessage

Now you have to create your `dService.ShowMessage(view, args)`  such that:
- it does not show the view
- it assumes an outcome of that action instead
- calls the lambda with the desired outcome